# How can I automatically start grunt watch upon opening a Visual Studio project/solution?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, gruntjs, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to have Visual Studio automatically run `grunt watch` for a specific solution or project once it's opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can run task using pre and post compile hooks in your project properties.

You can't run watch task from there though - if you do it'll simply block the compilation.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible using [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708).

Right click your task->Bindings->Solution Open

[image]